# ownCloud Alternative on Rooted Samsung Galaxy Note II

Tags: sync, files

### My question in short:

I want a cloud storage, but on my own servers. I know there's [Owncloud for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.owncloud.android), but it's quite limited. Is it possible to get a similar "user experience" like with other cloud services, with your own "cloud resources"? How could that be done?

**Please note that the phone is rooted.**

### Closer explanation:

I have tried searching for an alternative on [alternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net/software/owncloud/?platform=android) but didn't find anything particular to my scenario. I'm mainly seeking to find a solution that does not require the installation of an app.

I'd like to be able to:

- Instantly sync photos taken by camera to owncloud
- Sync latest Titanium Backup files
- Selectively sync other files and folders

I realize owncloud's Android app can do all of the above, but I'd like to know if this can be done **without** an app.

The screenshots below may give you an idea of what I have in mind. Can the function in the first screenshot at the left be replicated in such a way that we can use ownCloud? The other three screenshots show that I can add a server, but not a file sync server - which is what I need - ownCloud in my case.

[image: Samsung Galaxy Note II screenshots]

Comment: I'm afraid that falls into the *Is there an app for X* category, which our [help/on-topic] lists as being explicitly off topic. Reading it a 3rd time: maybe we can re-phrase that into "how can I achieve this with OwnCloud on a rooted device"? Would that match your request? I'll transform that for now (to prevent your well-researched question from being closed), you can always "revert" my changes.

Comment: If I remember correctly, OwnCloud does include support for either FTP, SFTP or FTPS? If so, I might have a working combination I'm even using myself on multiple devices, though not directly with OwnCloud.

Comment: Just realized my typo. I meant "but I'd like to know if this can be done **without** an app." Fixed. Does this render my question valid? If not, you may migrate it to the proper sub-forum or delete it if necessary.

Comment: ...and no problem. Your edits are welcome. They made the question clearer.

Comment: No, I think it's perfectly fine now: you're looking for a *solution*, not specificall for a certain app. Could you answer the question in my last comment: Can you access your OwnCloud server via FTP/SFTP/FTPS?

Comment: That's great. Moving on, I got carried away and didn't answer your question! No, ownCloud [does not support](http://owncloud.org/replacing-ftp-or-ftp-we-dont-need-no-stinking-ftp/) FTP, SFTP or FTPS. It includes support for WebDAV.

Comment: That seems to do as well. Let me write an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining several apps you most likely find useful for other means as well, this should be accomplishable. So first, let's list the components:

- [Tasker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/tasker/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm): the mighty automation tool will trigger several actions for us
- [FolderSync](http://www.appbrain.com/app/foldersync-lite/dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite): will do the real copy/sync jobs
- [Titanium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/titanium-backup-%E2%98%85-root/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) will do your backups (well, it does already).

No need to elaborate on *Titanium Backup*, as you already use it. Most likely together with its integrated scheduler, so you have an idea about what time that job has finished.

So the next candidate is *FolderSync*. It obviously can do with *OwnCloud*, as described e.g. in [Use the Android App FolderSync with ownCloud](https://portknox.net/en/tutorials/use-the-android-app-foldersync-with-owncloud) – using WebDAV, in fact. Which means you've first to setup your *OwnCloud* account in *FolderSync* (as described in the linked short-tut), and then define "folder pairs", i.e. which folder on your device should be sync'd with which on the *OwnCloud* server. Recommendation: configure it for *manual sync*; as nice as the integrated scheduler might sound, I experienced it woke up the device all 5 minutes 24/7 even with only one *daily* sync configured. So better leave that integrated scheduler off, we either need something else to trigger your "instant photo upload".

Third candidate: *Tasker*. You can use this to schedule your regular sync intervals (easy to do, as it's just a time interval as condition, and the *FolderSync* pair as the task; note this might require the Pro version of *FolderSync* for Tasker support). But *Tasker* has also means to detect whether a file/directory has been modified. This is what you can use to trigger your "instant photo upload", by watching your `DCIM` folder(s) and trigger the corresponding "folder pair" to be sync'd.

---

I know you prefered "without an app", but I don't know about such an alternative. However, one of the 3 apps involved you're using already, and once you've got used to *Tasker* you will ask yourself how you could do without. True, it's "payware", but worth every cent. For testing purposes, a 7-day-trial can be obtained on their project site; export all your config from within the app on day 6, uninstall, re-install, and import it again gives you another 7 days (recommendation by the dev himself). *FolderSync* requires 3 bucks as well; but it supports so many services, and has *Tasker* integration, I'd say it's worth the investment. So altogether ~7 bucks for a good solution, and other uses reserved.

Comment: This is such an elaborate clear-cut concise answer. I will most probably purchase FolderSync and Tasker as per your suggestion. Many thanks for the great effort Izzy!

Comment: Glad you like it! That's how my backup strategy works :) Besides: *Tasker* will take you some time to really get used to (but you'll never regret having spent it). In case you get stuck, remember we have a [tasker tag (wiki)](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) as well ;)